# Timezone changes to GMT in dataframe with Impala connection

Tags: r, sql-server, timezone, impala

I am connecting to database through Impala using R.I have a date column in my dataset and I am working on GMT+3 timezone. When I connect to database this is how I get my data displayed.

```
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/root/.../sqljdbc4-2.0.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://port",<user>, <password>)

dbGetQuery(conn, "select eventdate from sample")
```

Below is the result.

```
eventdate      
1     2017-01-31
2     2017-01-31
3     2017-01-31
4     2017-01-31 
5     2017-01-31 
6     2017-01-31
```

But my requirement is to connect through impala to sqlserver and which is done as below.

```
drv <- JDBC("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver","/root/.../ImpalaJDBC41.jar")       

impala <- src_impala(drv, "jdbc:impala://host","username", "password")

dbGetQuery(impala, "select eventdate from sample")
```

and I get the result as

```
eventdate 
1 2017-01-30 21:00:00.000000000
2 2017-01-30 21:00:00.000000000
3 2017-01-30 21:00:00.000000000
4 2017-01-30 21:00:00.000000000
5 2017-01-30 21:00:00.000000000
```

So by default it is taking timezone GMT and removing 3 hours from actual data. How to prevent this from happening.

Is it possible to change the timezone while connecting itself? Extracting the data and changing the time using `tz()` might not work in my case because this is a huge dataset and extracting itself takes time.

Comment: Do you have to use `jdbc`? Maybe try `odbc` driver with `as.is = TRUE`, i.e. `sqlQuery(con, q, as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: are you saying odbc connection for impala? I have not tried that let me try. But isn't `odbc` slower than `jdbc`? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, `odbc` connection for impala. I connect impala through `odbc` but haven't really noticed that slowness..

Answer (score 0):

Try the lubridate package. Easiest way I know of to work with timezones in R:

```
library(lubridate)
with_tz(Sys.time(),"Etc/GMT+3" )
# [1] "2019-03-14 03:39:07 -03"
with_tz(Sys.time(),'UTC')
# [1] "2019-03-14 06:39:27 UTC"
```

You can see valid time zone names for your OS with the command `OlsonNames()`. Alternatively, you can force the timezone with the function `force_tz()`

```
t
[1] "2019-03-14 06:46:06 UTC"
force_tz(t,'Etc/GMT+3')
[1] "2019-03-14 06:46:06 -03"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My `Sys.time()` is GMT+3 itself but while connecting to impala and executing the query it shows GMT. Are you suggesting to change the timezone after impala connection?

Comment: Yes. One of  `with_tz()` or `force_tz()` should give you the right answer once you get the data into R. If the timestamp was supposed to be say 6 PM GMT+3, but instead shows 3 PM GMT, use `with_tz()`. If it shows 6 PM GMT, then use `force_tz()`